# Convert pdf to text in regional language

Tags: windows, pdf

I have a pdf file rendered in regional language. Is there any way to extract the text content from it to use elsewhere?

**Edit:** The pdf contains real text; not images. I tried some online tools to convert to a word document , but some characters are messed up.

Comment: Please become familiar with the rules of this site. For a recommendation, we need to know which OS, which price etc.

Comment: @ThomasWeller It doesn't matter. Even an online tool will do. And regarding OS, I am using windows

Comment: That very much depends on whether the PDF contains "real text" or is just a collection of images. In the latter case, OCR would be needed – and for that a crucial criterion is what that "regional language" is. As Thomas pointed out, please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then [edit] your post accordingly. Otherwise you risk your question being closed as "unclear" or "too broad".

Comment: Are we really asking about a language here, or an alphabet? To me, it seems to tbe the latter

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive makes it painless to go paperless. Its collaborative documents, spreadsheets, and presentations already help curtail paper usage, but its OCR feature helps curb the paper mess even more so.

**Uploading to Google Drive**

To add your documents to Google Drive to get them OCRed, go in to your Google Drive account. On the My Drive page, click the Settings button on the right side of the page. Under Upload Settings, check off the Convert text from uploaded PDF and image files and the Confirm settings before each upload options.

[image]

Then, click the Upload button next to Create button on the left side of the page. Select Files, and find the file that you want to convert to text in Finder. Click Open.

An Upload Settings panel will appear. Select the proper language from the Document language drop-down menu, and leave the Confirm settings before each upload box checked.

Click Start upload once you have confirmed your settings. Upload progress can be monitored in the bottom right corner of the page. Uploads typically last around 30 seconds for image files and up to a minute for multipage PDFs.

read more @ [How to OCR Documents for Free in Google Drive](https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-ocr-documents-for-free-in-google-drive--cms-20460)